# What does the "Dual-band Wi-Fi" option do?

Tags: wi-fi, settings

On my Zenfone 8 running Android 13, what does the setting for "Dual-band WiFi" do? It's located under Settings > Network & internet > Internet.

[image: internet settings]

Comment: Without dual-band setting enabled is your device able to list any Wifi which is operating on 5 GHz frequency? This setting  *might* have to do with that.

Answer (score 0):

The dual band WiFi mode allows you to be connected to two different WiFi networks at the same time. You can select a Primary network and a Secondary network as fallback.

Technically it isn't the correct terminology, it might seem to have something to do with the 2.4/5GHz bands, but it doesn't.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).